# Problema con la propiedad android visibility en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

Tengo dos 'RelativeLayout' con bastante contenido cada uno, dentro de un ScrollView. En teoría son 3 páginas (llevo 2, me falta una) con instrucciones y al final el resultado. Para no crear tantos archivos xml, intento poner las dos páginas en un solo archivo. Cada página tiene un botón al final que lleva al usuario a la siguiente página, aquí es donde ocurre mi problema.

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando el usuario le dé clic al botón 'siguiente', el primer RelativeLayout desaparezca con setVisibility(View.GONE) para entonces llamar al segundo RelativeLayout y ponerlo visible. Aquí me salta el siguiente error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

Cuando elimino la acción del botón y voy al xml para hacer una prueba forzada poniendo al primer RelativeLayout con visibility="gone" y dejo el segundo RelativeLayout con visibility="visible", entonces no me muestra nada. Es como si no viera el segundo RelativeLayout.

Siento que puede ser porque cargué con mucho contenido un xml, o quizás porque se trate de un fragment.
De igual manera les dejo el código por si ven algo que yo no.

fragmento_cuentas.xml

[image: IMAGEN1]

Clase Fragmento_Cuentas

```
public class Fragmento_Cuentas extends Fragment {

    private View vista;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout1, relativeLayout3;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmento_cuentas, container,false);

        inicializar();
        return vista;
    }

    private void inicializar() {
        relativeLayout1 = vista.findViewById(R.id.pag_1);
        relativeLayout3 = vista.findViewById(R.id.pag_3);
        Button boton1 = vista.findViewById(R.id.boton_1);

        boton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                relativeLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                relativeLayout3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

PD: Disculpen por usar imagen, no pude subir todo el código porque me decía que me pasaba de la cantidad de caracteres permitidos aquí. Si necesitan ver todo el contenido del xml díganmelo para buscar la manera de mostrárselos.

Comment: probaste ustilizando ConstraintLayout a ver que pasa.
Te dejo un articulo para que veas la diferencia entre uno y otro. <https://codearmy.co/android-relative-vs-constraint-layouts-cual-es-mejor-y-como-usarlo-95c08582ab2e>

Comment: solo puedes tener un Layout hijo directamente en un ScrollView. Lo que puedes hacer es un RelativeLayout (dentro del Scrollview) y dento de el poner los otros layouts.

Comment: Al realizar lo que dices (@armen) sí me muestra los dos layout al modificar directamente en el xml si están visibles o no, pero al momento de ejecutar el programa, me sigue saliendo el error de NullPointerException. La verdad no entiendo porqué  lo ve como null, si lo inicié y asigné a la variable correctamente... o eso creo. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: Con respecto a lo que dices (@ptorresi), creo que daría igual que tipo de layout es, no debería lanzarme ese error. Pienso que usar ConstraintLayout más bien sería para reducir tantos layouts que uso, aunque igual intentaré hacer el cambio. Gracias por contestar.

Comment: Yo pienso lo mismo que vos. La verdad que no lo exprese en la respuesta. Pense que utilizando Constraint a lo mejor te complicarias menos. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema. No me había dado cuenta que se había creado otra carpeta llamada 'layout-v21', contenía el mismo archivo XML (fragmento_cuentas.xml) pero sin el segundo RelativeLayout (llamado 'pag_3').

Por eso al momento de correrlo en mi celular, en vez de utilizar el archivo 'fragmento_cuentas.xml' de la carpeta 'layout', utilizaba el de la carpeta 'layout-v21'.